# rm scheduling - calculation

Tags: real-time, scheduling, scheduler

If there are 3 independent tasks using preemptive RM scheduling. The total utilization is 0.73. Is system feasible? 
My opinion: Can I calculate it on basis of: if utilization is less then or equal to 1 then it is feasible.

Or, how can I make sure of system is feasible or not?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As said on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling), the test to see is a system is feasible with n tasks is usage <= n(2^1/n -1) , in your case it gives 0.78, so 0.73 is feasible.

Your global reasoning is however invalid.